# Python Input EOF Error in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I've been trying to get input from the user in python using this code:

```
workingDir = " "
def specifyDir():
    #workingDir = raw_input("Enter Working Dir")
    workingDir = input("Enter Working Dir")
specifyDir()
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/akrapf/Desktop/Misc/Programming/Python/Catalog/catalog.py", line 14, in <module>
    specifyDir()
  File "/Users/akrapf/Desktop/Misc/Programming/Python/Catalog/catalog.py", line 11, in specifyDir
    workingDir = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/akrapf/Desktop/Misc/Programming/Python/Catalog/catalog.py"]
```

I've tried researching this, and I found multiple people saying to use SublimeREPL to fix this. I've installed this and tried again with no luck. Neither `raw_input()` or `input()` work.

Comment: @BobDylan SublimeREPL works perfectly fine with ST3. The issue you referenced is 2.5 years old, and doesn't claim the program doesn't work - did you actually read it? Don't comment about things you don't understand.